# Math necessary for offsetting columns?

Tags: c, linux

I have a project where I need to print the contents of a directory in lexicographical order with a variable amount of columns dependent on the current width of the terminal window, and the contents are printed vertically with the columns all of equal length.

I have most of the base idea done, basically I just divided the terminal window width by the arbitrary number I set for the allowed column length (in this case 22 so the amount of file names printed per row is always window_width/22, so for example if the window_width is 88, 88/22 is 4 so each row will have at max 4 file names, the amount of blank spaces is the difference between the file name length and 22).

I figured out all the lexicographical stuff and printing files from a directory is all done, I am just struggling right now with figuring out the math I need to use to print out the everything in a vertical fashion. I have tried to write down some ideas but I'm still stuck and don't know how to begin. I have tried to spitball around a few code ideas, but all of them end up with a segmentation fault (no doubt due to trying to figure out a way to offset the array as I will explain below) or just print out files in an unintended manner.

So for example, if my directory has

```
f1, f2, f3, f4, f5, f6, f7, f8, f9, f10, f11, f12, f13
```

then it should print out something like this:

```
f1  f5  f8  f11
f2  f6  f9  f12
f3  f7  f10 f13
f4
```

I know that once I print out a line, I can't return to it, so I have to figure out a way to print f1 f5 f8 f11 at once, and the same all the way down.

All the file names are stored in an array, so I was thinking of offsetting it somehow so for example rowWidth (which in this case is 4), i = 0, arr[i + rowWidth * 0] is f1, arr[i + rowWidth * 1] is f5, but then arr[i + rowWidth * 2] should be f8, so that means in the first column, the distance between the first and second elements is 4 (which is due to height of col 1), but every other column, the distance is only 3 (because all cols after 1 are height 3).

I think this has something to do with the division of column length and window width leaving a remainder, but I don't really know how I can determine the length of all columns before printout and how I can distribute the array offset properly.

I'm not really sure how I should handle this, it feels like this situation requires a lot of foresight so I don't want to jump in again until I have a solid idea of what method I should use.

Comment: You need to process the data in two passes.  The first pass needs to calculate the maximum width of each column, storing the results in an array.  The second pass can then output the result in a tabular format, padding each field to the maximum width for its column.

Comment: @TomKarzes you are saying I should store each row in an array with elements = row size? (so for example in this case since each row has 4 elements, an array of size 4?) That is a good idea, I was only thinking of using a confusing series of for loops but making a new array sounds much easier, thank you. My only problem now is trying to figure out how to determine the column height to appropriately offset each element (for example distance between f1 and f5 is 4, but f5 and f8 is 3....)

Comment: Oh ok sorry I now realize you are listing the entries going down columns.  In this case yes I would read the whole thing in, then based on the number of entries you can decide how many rows are needed, then you can work out the column widths to line up the entries.

Comment: Once you determine which row and column each entry is in, just go through each column to determine the maximum width needed for all entries in that column.  Store the results in a small integer array indexed by column number.  Once you have that, you can just pad out each field to the maximum width for its column.

Comment: In your example, the maximum width for the first two columns is 2 and the second two columns is 3, so your width array would contain {2, 2, 3, 3}.

Comment: @TomKarzes Oh! I understand completely now, thank you so much sir, I know exactly where to take it from here. I've been looking at code all week for so long that I needed a fresh set of eyes to show the answer that was right in front of me